# HTTParty - JSON to strongly typed object

Tags: ruby, httparty

Is it possible to have HTTParty deserialize the results from a GET to a strongly typed ruby object? For example

```
class Myclass
 include HTTParty

end

x = Myclass.get('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tags=HTTParty')

puts x.total
puts x.questions[0].title
```

Right now it deserializes it into a hash

```
puts x["total"]
```

My question is actually if HTTParty supports this OTB, not by installing additional gems.

**Edit**:

I'm still new to Ruby, but I recall that class fields are all private so they would need to be accessed through getter/setter methods. So maybe this question isn't a valid one?

Comment: All you are going to get from a GET request is text. If that text represents a serialised ruby object, then you can unserialise it and get a ruby object. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: What comes back from the GET is json, but HTTParty deserializes it into a hash, but I would like the json to be deserialized into a strongly typed object. The keyword here is DESERIALIZE which I failed to put in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want the return value of `Myclass::get` to be an instance of `Myclass`. If that's the case, you could cache the return value from the HTTP request and implement `method_missing` to return values from that hash:

```
class Myclass
  include HTTParty

  attr_accessor :retrieved_values

  def method_missing(method, *args, &block)
    if retrieved_values.key?(method)
      retrieved_values[method]
    else
      super
    end
  end

  def self.get_with_massaging(url)
    new.tap do |instance|
      instance.retrieved_values = get_without_massaging(url)
    end
  end

  class << self
    alias_method :get_without_massaging, :get
    alias_method :get, :get_with_massaging
  end
end
```

This isn't exactly what you asked for, because it only works one level deep — i.e., `x.questions[0].title` would need to be `x.questions[0][:title]`

```
x = Myclass.get('http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tags=HTTParty')
p x.total
p x.questions[0][:title]
```

Perhaps you could come up with some hybrid of this answer and Joshua Creek's to take advantage of OpenStruct.

I should also point out that all the method aliasing trickery isn't necessary if your method doesn't *have* to be named `get`.

Answer (score 2):

If you are just wanting method syntax, you can use an open struct.

```
require 'httparty'
require 'ostruct'

result = HTTParty.get 'http://api.stackoverflow.com/1.0/questions?tags=HTTParty'
object = OpenStruct.new result
object.total # => 2634237
```

A possible downside is that this object is totally open such that if you invoke a nonexistent method on it, it will just return nil (if you invoke a setter, it will create both the setter and getter)